# If $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $R[x]$ then $f(h(x))$ divides $g(h(x))$ in $R[x]$ (?).

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $f(x),~g(x)\in R[x]$ be polynomials of $x$ over a ring $R$. Suppose that $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$. Can we say that $f(h(x))$ divides $g(h(x))$ for all polynomials $h(x)\in R[x]$?

I am almost convinced that the answer is yes, but I don't know how to prove it exactly. I know that $x$ is a "fixed" quantity in the frame of 
$R[x],$ so we can not just pass the equation $g(x)=\pi(x)\,f(x)$ to $g(h(x))=\pi(h(x))\,f(h(x))$, although it seems to be very logical to happen.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If $g(x)=f(x)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is another polynomial, then $$g(h(x))=f(h(x))q(h(x))=f(h(x))Q(x)$$ where $q(h(x))=Q(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$.

Comment: Which argument do you use to pass from $g(x)=f(x)q(x)$ to $g(h(x))=f(h(x))\,q(h(x))$? (we are not in Real Analysis, so that $x$ is a variable and takes values on an interval)

Comment: @NikolaosSkout But we are in Abstract Algebra and can define a ring homomorphism $R[x]\to R[x]$ which is identity on $R$ and sends $x$ to $h(x)$.